# How to dynamically get the field value from object result in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I want to take the field value dynamically in lightning controller . I got the object result but unable to the field value.

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.getFieldValues");
    action.setParams({
        sObjectName :component.get("v.sObjectName"),
        fieldNames  :component.get("v.fieldNames")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

        var state = response.getState();            
        var fieldArray = [];
        fieldArray = component.get("v.fieldNames").split(',');
        console.log('###'+fieldArray[0]);
        var accFieldName=fieldArray[0];

        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var objData = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('####gotFieldValue'+objData.Name); // this line value is getting values
            console.log('####NoValue'+objData.accFieldName); //this line value is not getting 
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Here for objData I am getting the value. If i try to take (objData.Name) the account name is coming .But i want to pass the field value dynamically from 
fieldNames.It is not working .

Please help me !!

Comment: do you want to get field values dynamically from list of fields?

Comment: yes,I want to get the fields dynamically

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, to dynamically get field of object you should use obj[FIELD].

Try this line instead:

```
console.log('####NoValue'+objData[accFieldName]);
```

Please mark it as solution once it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all fields, try this.

```
//read key
for (var key in objData) {
   console.log(key);
   console.log(objData[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the field value like below :

```
 console.log('####gotFieldValue'+objData[accFieldName]);
```

Comment: No idea why you respond to yourself instead of marking the current answer for who actually helped you